How to write a resillient object oriented method for SQL Update Table with retry in catch
I need a method that tries to update a table several times. This was my first try.
void UpdateSomeSQLRows(uint retryCount = 3)
{
    try
    {
        // Some Code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        retryCount--;

        if (retryCount != 0)
            UpdateSomeSQLRows(retryCount);
    }
}

Will it work resliliently for sql updates with native Microsoft sqlclient?

Only one method, no class or object - this code is not object-oriented at all.

Probably a bit opinion-based, but... I'd personally opt for a loop instead of recursion.  Within the loop you can catch exceptions (and log them, even as warning/info) and update the re-try count which drives the loop.  If the re-try count exceeds a given setting, throw a new exception.  (Or return some default, or whatever you want to do when the operation fails.)

this silently swallows exceptions if it fails all 3 times; maybe catch (Exception) when (retryCount > 0) ? although I kinda hate the recursion here

You are decreasing the retryCount an unnecessary time.

By the way, if you call your method with UpdateSomeSQLRows(0) you will have arround 4 billion retries

@SomeBody how about:         checked { retryCount--; }
inside the catch

There is a library called Polly that does this in a good way with many advanced features. This will also propagate the exception to the calling function after the last retry attempt instead of failing silently and also adds a delay between each attempt.
internal class Program
{
    private static Policy retrySqlPolicy = 
        Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateSomeSQLRows();
    }

    static void UpdateSomeSQLRows()
    {
        retrySqlPolicy.Execute(() =>
        {
            // Some Code
        });
    }
}

